# Unix glob() function and formal language equivalence

Tags: algorithms, pushdown-automata

Can we express the matching capabilities of [Unix library function `glob()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) using a single-stack push-down automata, i.e. set of context free formal languages? If not, which is the minimal automata that we need?

For those that do not know what `glob()` does, it is a pattern matcher generator using a few operators:

- `*` matches an unlimited number of consecutive characters. As this can be in any position, not only in the end of the pattern, I eliminated the possibility of expressing glob expressions in terms of regular expressions.
- `?` matches exactly one arbitrary character, which is similar to a skip state in a finite automaton.
- `[abc]` matches an arbitrary-length string consisting of only symbols in the brackets, and `[!abc]` matches an arbitrary-length string that includes anything but symbols in the brackets. Those character sets can also be listed in a shorthand notation like `[a-z]` or `[!a-z]`.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Are you familiar with regular expressions?  Have you made any progress?  Can you think of any relationship to anything you've learned in formal languages?

Comment: I have learned formal languages in computer engineering school, and familiar enough with UNIX that I concluded `glob()` cannot be expressed in regular expressions.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that.  Can you give an example of something that cannot be expressed with a regular expression?  I wonder if there is some aspect of glob I'm not familiar with.  Perhaps you could [edit] the question to give some background on glob(), to specify the capabilities that you think are most challenging to model in that way?  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29#Compared_to_regular_expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Every glob expression can be recognized with a regular expression (the translation is [straightforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29#Compared_to_regular_expressions)).  Every regular language is also context-free, and there is a straightforward translation: convert the regular expression to a DFA, then turn that into a pushdown automaton that never uses or looks at its stack.  So, it follows that every glob expression can be recognized by some pushdown automaton, i.e., it recognizes a context-free language.